# Extract dictionary from a string

Tags: kdb

I have got a string that represents a query. It begins with a function, and the argument is a dictionary.

```
"runQuery `syms`columns`fastQuery`exchange!((`AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD);(`sym`price`date);1b;`nasdaq)"
```

How can I extract the dictionary from the string, and save it in kdb as a dictionary type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse the string, to get the parse tree, and then take the param (the dict):

```
q)eval last parse "runQuery `syms`columns`fastQuery`exchange!((`AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD);(`sym`price`date);1b;`nasdaq)"
syms     | `AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD
columns  | `sym`price`date
fastQuery| 1b
exchange | `nasdaq
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example `value` can have the desired effect:

```
q)myDict:value {(first where x=" ")_x}"runQuery `syms`columns`fastQuery`exchange!((`AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD);(`sym`price`date);1b;`nasdaq)"
q)myDict
syms     | `AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD
columns  | `sym`price`date
fastQuery| 1b
exchange | `nasdaq
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I would lean towards using `reval` as well to protect against dangerous string code. `reval (value:x)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have free rein to (re)define the function then you could just do:

```
q)runQuery:{x}
q)value"runQuery `syms`columns`fastQuery`exchange!((`AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD);(`sym`price`date);1b;`nasdaq)"
syms     | `AAPL`MSFT`GOOG`AMD
columns  | `sym`price`date
fastQuery| 1b
exchange | `nasdaq
```

This could be quite useful if you're replaying a tickerplant-style log using `-11!`